# Calculator and Formatter classes

Tags: php, calculator

`Calculator` class:

```
class Calculator
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    function doPowTable ($n)
    {
        $table = array();
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++)
        {
            $table[] = array(
                'i' => $i,
                'factor' => pow($i, 2)
            );
        }
        return $table;
    }
}
```

`Formatter` class:

```
class Formatter
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    function getAndFormat ($n)
    {
        $table = (new Calculator()).doPowTable ($n);
        return array_map (function($item) {
            $item['i_factor'] = $item['i'].'_'.$item['factor'];
            return $item;
        }, $table);
    }
}
```

They say it's bad because the helper hard-codes the `Calculator`. But I think it's how it is supposed to be. It would have been better if I didn't give the `$n` to it but an array created by the `doPowTable()` method. Why?

Comment: Problem #1 .... `$table = (new Calculator()).doPowTable ($n);` the `.` in PHP is a concatenation operator; do you mean `$table = (new Calculator())->doPowTable ($n);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if I want to put the `Formatter` class under test? How can I mock the `Calculator` dependency if it is hard-coded?

I suggest you put that into a separate public method so that it would be possible for other developers to create a partial mock and test it. It will also be clearer since you start reading the class what its dependencies are.

```php
class Formatter
{
    /**
     * @var Calculator
     */ 
    private $calculator;

    /**
     * @param Calculator $calculator
     * @return $this     
     */
    public function setCalculator(Calculator $calculator)
    {
        $this->calculator = $calculator;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Calculator
     */
    public function getCalculator()
    {
        return $this->calculator;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    function getAndFormat ($n)
    {
        $table = $this->getCalculator()->doPowTable($n);

        return array_map (function($item) {
            $item['i_factor'] = $item['i'].'_'.$item['factor'];
            return $item;
        }, $table);
    }
}
```

This way you can either provide a different calculator or a mocked one for testing purposes.

Please consider the example below. It shows how to create a partial mock of the `Formatter` class to override the `Calculator` dependency.

```php
$mockedCalculator = $this->getMock(Calculator::class);

// set your mocked calculator behaviour here

$formatter = $this->getMockBuilder(Formatter::class)
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(['getCalculator'])
    ->getMock();

$formatter
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('getCalculator')
    ->willReturn($mockedCalculator);

$n = 123; // it's just an example
$this->assertEquals($expectedValue, $formatter->getAndFormat($n));
```